# Shell script giving errors in ksh

Tags: linux, bash, shell, solaris, ksh

I have a script which runs fine when executed in Bash shell (with Red Hat Linux), however this same script which fails on a Solaris 10 (DB) server where `ksh` is being used to execute this script. This script basically reads line by line from a file and executes a stored proc (in Oracle).  Below is my script :

```
#/bin/sh

for i in $(cat subscriber.txt); do

        SUBSCRIBER_ID="'$i'"
        sqlplus -s myuser/myuser  <<EOF
        execute delete_learnings($SUBSCRIBER_ID);
        commit;
        EXIT    
EOF
done
```

The error I get is :

```
./removeLearnings.sh: syntax error at line 3: `$' unexpected
```

Any idea what might be going wrong? Should I change the script to have the `ksh`? I am not able to debug on this machine since it's a customer environment (which I don't have access to).

Comment: Solaris `/bin/sh` is not POSIX compliant and does not recognize the `$(…)` notation — unless, perhaps, you have Solaris 11.  Note that you're not using `ksh`; the shebang says `#!/bin/sh` and not `#!/bin/ksh`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is the `$(...)` construction which is POSIX compliant but unsupported by the legacy Bourne shell which `/bin/sh` is on Solaris 10 and older.

You can either replace your shebang to call the Solaris POSIX compliant shell:

```
#!/usr/xpg4/bin/sh
```

or use this legacy syntax (less recommended):

```
for i in `cat subscriber.txt`; do
```

Comment: Either one of these should work right ? Sorry I am asking basic questions , kinda of a noob in unix :)

Comment: Cool , I've asked them to change it. Once it works I will mark your answer as the correct one. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to execute a sh( bourne shell) script on ksh (Korn shell). Try changing the shebang (#!/bin/bash) to (#!/bin/ksh)

Answer (score 0):

Looping over text files with `for` is a bad idea, anyway. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001- the recommended syntax is more portable, too:

```
while read stuff; do
    : things with "$stuff"
done <subscriber.txt
```

You would normally use `read -r` but I don't know if that's available on Solaris.

However, very often, a shell loop is altogether the wrong approach. A single SQL invocation is a lot better and more robust:

```
( sed 's/.*/execute delete_learnings(&);/'
  printf "commit;\nEXIT\n" ) |
sqlplus -s myuser/myuser
```